# Octave 4.0 crashing on audiowrite

Tags: octave

I'm trying to split up the long line of audiowrite but when I do Octave 4.0 crashes I'm using Octave 4.0 (which is like matlab) on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

```
audio_prop='BitsPerSample',16,'Artist','artist rt','Title','title section rt','Comment','Comments section rt';
audiowrite('/tmp/test.wav',[sig_full_L(:) -1*sig_full_R(:)],44100,audio_prop)
```

Can I not split it up this way if not how can I split it up?

Someone asked for the full code so here it is (this causes octave 4.0 to crash)

```
fs =8000;                    % Sampling frequency
fs_rate=fs;
dursec=10; %%duration of signal in seconds

t=linspace(0,2*pi,dursec*fs); 
freq=primes(fs/2*dursec);
freq=freq';

ya=zeros(1,length(t));
numfreq=numel(freq)

for ii=1:1:numel(freq)
    ya = ya+sin(freq(ii,1)*t); 
end
audio_prop='BitsPerSample',16,'Artist','artist rt','Title','title section rt','Comment','Comments section rt';
audiowrite('/tmp/test.flac',[ya(:) -1*ya(:)],44100,audio_prop)
```

I was told by the octave people to fill out a crash / bug report link below
https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47875

Comment: Please take time to give an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code given does not work at all. Even the first line is wrong. Brackets (`{}`)are missing around it. And it should be `audio_prop{:}` in the second line.

Comment: @ederag I added more code but the problem is with the two original  lines I was having problems with

Comment: @ederag yes it was syntax problem in those two lines.  Thanks

Comment: did you try to copy-paste your sample into an octave session ? Here it yields syntax error (again).

Comment: @ederag your comment about it being a syntax {} and {:} fixed the problem if you make that as an answer I'll mark it as you solving it.

Comment: So the term "crash" in the title is wrong. It was a syntax error, not a crash (like segmentation fault), right ? Next time, please give the error message.

Comment: @ederag no it causes a crash I was told by the octave people to submit a bug report see link below
https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47875

Comment: Thanks for the bug report. No syntax error should lead to a crash. It was quickly fixed (5 days) by the octave team. Besides, your question is now in a correct state.

Comment: Not sure why this was downgraded since it was a bug in Octave....and I had to fill out a bug report for them to fix the code.

Comment: The downvotes probably came from the first version of the question, which was missing a [mcve], obviously important to allow potential helpers to run the code, and reproduce the error. Lacking the [mcve], they assumed, like me, that it was a mere syntax error, and that crash was not the appropriate word.

Comment: Besides, kindly and just because I interpret your last comment as a will to understand. The fact that you added "Someone asked for the full code" shows to me that at that time you had not read the [mcve] page carefully. Have you since ? Do you now see why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to wrap a long list of arguments into a single variable,
in order to shorter lines or to allow for reuse in a further function.

First put the arguments in a [cell array](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Basic-Usage-of-Cell-Arrays.html#Basic-Usage-of-Cell-Arrays).

```
options = {"a", "b", 2};
```

Then use the cell array expansion, which is a bit hidden [there](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Indexing-Cell-Arrays.html#Indexing-Cell-Arrays) :

> Accessing multiple elements of a cell array with the ‘{’ and ‘}’
>   operators will result in a [comma separated list](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Comma-Separated-Lists.html#Comma-Separated-Lists) of all the requested
>   elements

In our case,

```
options{:}
```

is interpreted as

```
"a", "b", 2
```

so calling

```
func(arg1, arg2, options{:})
```

is interpreted as

```
func(arg1, arg2, "a", "b", 2)
```

Which answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

@ederag solved this for me. "Even the first line is wrong. Brackets ({})are missing around it. And it should be audio_prop{:} in the second line."

The code with the error should be:

```
audio_prop={'BitsPerSample',16,'Artist','artist rt','Title','title section rt','Comment','Comments section rt'};
audiowrite('/tmp/test.wav',[sig_full_L(:) -1*sig_full_R(:)],44100,audio_prop{:})
```